# How to click on ALLOW of Show Notifications in chrome 76 using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, push-notification

I have already tried below solution but no luck!!!

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();

//1-Allow, 2-Block, 0-default

prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Output: Notifications in the browser will be set to "Ask before sending" but website is not listed under the 'Allow' in settings, to receive push notifications

Comment: What output did you get from it?

Comment: Notifications in the browser will be set to "Ask before sending" but website is not listed under the 'Allow' in settings, to receive push notifications

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try the below code, it will set the browser notification to allow (by default) on the chrome browser.**

**Step 1:**

It will create a map to store your preferences

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

**Step 2:**

```
//Now add key and value to map, 1 means to allow and 2 means to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
```

**Step 3:**

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

**Step 4:**

```
//Now Pass it on to the ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

**Note:** *Please check whether you are following **step 4** or not. ChromeOptions instance need to be passed to the ChromeDriver Constructor to initialize chrome driver which will switch on the notification on the chrome browser.*